# ExtJs4 Mapping a treeStore level to a Store

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, grid, extjs4, store

What is a good way to map a level of a treestore to a flat store. In my case,

I want to group criteria for a search. All search criteria are inserted into the top level of the treeStore, unless they are grouped, in which case they become children of a top level logical(AND or OR) node. So, within a grid, I want to display the top level nodes (via some toString method I will define in the model). This is the easy part, I just go through the top level of my tree and generate the output for the Store/grid. However, when I want to remove something from the grid/store, it also needs to be removed from the treestore which represents the actual logical structure.

So, How can I keep track of which textual store item corresponds to which top level node in my treeStore?

Comment: Please publish your tree and grid models.

Comment: The grid model is an implicit model with a single field for the text I generate, there is no model there. The tree model contains various fields. The field content of the model's isn't really of any concern, unless enlisting an identifier field is a reasonable solution to the problem, although that would introduce another layer of complexity.

Comment: I was thinking of two solutions. First one is of course introducing an Id field in models. Second one is to use filters.

Comment: What would the filter solution look like?

Comment: You can define a filter to filter records in a store by checking certain field/fields. Filters and can be added to store config's filters collection.

Answer (score 0):

Load your data onto the store or treegrid (but not both), then collect the records from one object and just add them to the other (using store.add() or treestore.getRootNode().appendChild()).  At this point if you have a reference to the record, you can just say store.remove([record]); and then treestore.getRootNode().removeChild(record); to remove it from both.